# Figwheel doesn't detect most changes in my code

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

Figwheel displays the code bellow just fine. But I have to refresh the page to see any changes. What has to change for Figwheel to show changes? Is there a command to force redraw, without losing the application state?

BTW: *Chrome has Disable Cache **true** and the CLJS icon appears when the file is saved*.

```
(defn simple-example []
  [ui/mui-theme-provider {:mui-theme (get-mui-theme
                                       {:palette {:text-color (color :blue800)}})}
   [:div
    [ui/app-bar {:title                 "Hi all"
                 :icon-class-name-right "muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"}]
    [ui/paper
     [:div
      [ui/tabs
       [ui/tab {:label "Menu" :value "0"}
        [:div "Hello world"]]]]]]]))

(defn ^:export run []
  (render [simple-example]
          (js/document.getElementById "app"))))
```

Comment: Do you get the "cljs-icon" popup after your writes each time?  So is figwheel not loading your changes or have the changes not appearant effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel):

> Setting `:figwheel true` or `:figwheel { :on-jsload "example.core/reload-hook" }` will automagically insert the figwheel client code into your application. If you supply `:on-jsload` the name of a function, that function will be called after new code gets reloaded.

An example reload hook plus configuration for Reagent:

```
(ns your-namespace.core
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]))


(defn render [view]
  (let [node (.getElementById js/document "app")]
    (r/render-component view node)))


(defn rerender []
  (let [node (.getElementById js/document "app")]
    (r/unmount-component-at-node node)
    (render [:div "Reloading"]))


(defn ^:export reload []
  (rerender))
```

And then in your `project.clj`:

```
:cljsbuild {:builds {:dev {:source-paths ["src"] 
                           :figwheel     {:on-jsload "your-namespace.core/reload"}}}
```

/edit

Note that re-frame uses Reagent. In the case of re-frame I recommend starting with the [`re-frame-template`](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-template). E.g.,

```
lein new re-frame your-project-name # options, e.g., +re-frisk +cider
```

This will give a default `core.cljs` as follows:

```
(defn dev-setup []
  (when config/debug?
    (enable-console-print!)
    (println "dev mode")))

(defn mount-root []
  (re-frame/clear-subscription-cache!)
  (reagent/render [views/main-panel]
                  (.getElementById js/document "app")))

(defn ^:export init []
  (re-frame/dispatch-sync [:initialize-db])
  (dev-setup)
  (mount-root))
```

The `index.html` has a node with id `app` and calls `init`. And the `project.cljs` specifies the `on-jsload` as follows:

```
:cljsbuild
{:builds
 [{:id           "dev"
   :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
   :figwheel     {:on-jsload "your-project-name.core/mount-root"}
#_(...)}}
```

This should absolutely update the page with the component changed. If it does not do what you want I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I'm using [re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame). `:figwheel true` doesn't work. For `:figwheel { :on-jsload "example.core/reload-hook" }`, which function should I call (re-frame uses functions that return functions to create components)?

Comment: @dilvan I updated the answer for re-frame. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Reagent needs to be notified about state changes to re-render the affected components on the screen. Your code does not yet have any inner state that can be watched in order to decide if a re-render is required.

You can store your app state in *reagent atoms*. When you dedreference a reagent atom in a reagent component (that is the `simple-example` component in your case) an event listener is set up to the state atom so that any time it changes the component will be re-rendered.

Put the following just before the definition of `simple-example`:

```
(defonce counter (reagent.core/atom 0))
(swap! counter inc)
```

This creates a state called `counter` if it does not exist yet. It also immediately increases it so any already registered components will be refreshed.

Then put a `@counter` deref call anywhere inside the function body of `simple-example`. This way the initial call of the function installs the state change listeners.

Now any time you modify the code the namespace get reloaded and thus `counter` atom increases triggering the re-render of your component.

Comment: Thanks! But my problem remains: there will be code outside react components that needs to be changed. Isn't there a command to force the re-render of the screen (or of all components)? Maybe a REPL command? (BTW, I am using re-frame).

Comment: Maybe put a `(deref state-atom)` inside the root component?

Comment: I'm using re-frame, how can I do that? BTW, is that the recommended way of doing that in figwheel?